# Nested Set Model: Inserting Node at the end of SubNodes

Tags: sql, nested-sets

Existing Data (name, lft, rgt):

```
Root, 1, 4
Item1, 2, 3
```

Looks like:

```
- Root
--- Item1
```

How do you insert a new node (Item2) BELOW Item1?  My system's current logic follows most examples I've found online but the result is Item2 ABOVE Item1.

```
- Root
--- Item1
--- Item2
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of the nested sets model as of an `XML` file with `lft` and `rgt` being the lines where the staring and ending tags reside:

```
1  <root>
2   <item1>
3   </item1>
4  </root>
```

To insert a new subtag into the `root`, you'll need to shift down all subsequent records:

```
1  <root>
2   <item1>
3   </item1>
4   <item2>
5   </item2>
6  </root>
```

So you'll need to calculate the `item2.lft` and `item2.rgt` (which are the `item2.rgt + 1` and `item1.rgt + 2`, accordingly), and then increment **all** `lft` and `rgt` of **all** items which are greater than the `item1.rgt`:

```
UPDATE  mytable
SET     rgt = rgt + 2
WHERE   rgt > item1.rgt

UPDATE  mytable
SET     lft = lft + 2
WHERE   lft > item1.rgt
```

Comment: Second update should be `WHERE left > item1.lft` - it shouldn't use the right value.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName: it should compare left values to `item1.rgt` too, otherwise it would shift items inside `item1` (if any).

Comment: Yes, you're right; I was thinking of adding to a parent.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the "correct answer" is correct, what you should do is:
set item2.lft = root.rgt  (4)
set item2.rgt = root.rgt + 1 (5)

UPDATE  mytable
SET     rgt = rgt + 2
WHERE   rgt >= root.rgt
root.rgt is 6 now;

UPDATE  mytable
SET     lft = lft + 2
WHERE   lft > root.rgt
root.lft stays the same (1), but you have multiple roots, they will get updated.

You can't use a peer entry to determine the lft and rgt values.

Answer (score 1):

```
Root, 1, 6
Item1, 2, 3
Item2, 4, 5
```

and use `ORDER BY ItemName`, but of course this only works for a given set of siblings.

For how to insert, see the 5th query here: http://intelligent-enterprise.informationweek.com/001020/celko.jhtml;jsessionid=OOU0L1TIM1IB1QE1GHPSKH4ATMY32JVN

Some people put gaps between their numbers to try to minimize the number of `UPDATE`s that have to be done. This performance issue can only be partially alleviated though, and is intrinsic to the nested set model. For this reason many people implement other hierarchical models, like [materialized path](http://www.dbazine.com/oracle/or-articles/tropashko4).

Comment: Understand that... I was looking for some help with the procedure logic

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for.  That SP that was based on 'rgt' rather than 'lft'... perfect.